# Override on Field initialization

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

For the following example,

```
public abstract class RecordData {
  private MyDate mDate  = new MyDate(new SimpleDateFormat(""yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

  public Date getMyDate() {
    return mDate.getDate();
  }    
  .....
  }
```

I would like implementing classes to override the date format. One way of doing this is to have a method like this:

```
protected SimpleDateFormat getDateForm() {
  return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
}
```

So,the initialization should be like:
   `MyDate mDate  = new MyDate(getDateForm());`

Is there any other convenient way of doing this. What are the potential issues with the above implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing that is a very bad idea: your base class would call a methog of the subclass in its constructor, and would thus call a method on an object that hasn't been initialized yet. You'd better pass all the data needed by the superclass in its constructor:

```
public abstract class RecordData {
    private MyDate mDate;

    protected RecordData(String datePattern) {
        this.mDate = new MyDate(new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern));
    }
}
```

Doing how others suggest would completely break with such a basic implementation:

```
public class SubRecordData extends RecordData {
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;

    public SubRecordData(String pattern) {
        this.dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    }

    // broken: when this method is called by the base class constructor, 
    // dateFormat is still null
    @Override
    protected SimpleDateFormat getDateFormat() {
        return dateFormat;
    }
}
```